# Not able to build project in release mode but build in debug mode

Tags: c++

My project is in Window Runtime component which we made to use C++ DLL in UWP (c#)application. Now I am able to build project in debug mode successfully and run it properly in my UWP application but when I tried to build project in release mode then it is not build in release mode and return below error.

```
Error :
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'XXXBase.h': No such file or directory    XYZWRC  d:\projects\demo\pch.h  6
```

I am new in WRC and don't have much knowledge of it. Do I need to do any additional configuration for release mode and if yes what and from where?

Comment: Is XXXBase.h actually included in the build for release? Rightclick and check the property 'Excluded from build'. In general check that file for any differences you don't want between release and debug version.

Comment: This more often than not is on account of different include paths in debug/release configurations. I used to run into this frequently while working on Visual Studio slns where these paths have  to be manually maintained for each configuration.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I found the root cause, it happened because of some third party DLL paths is not defined in release mode but set it in debug mode, I set those paths in release mode same as debug mode and then it start to build in release mode.